# Create Picture Library in sharepoint app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to create Picture Library in sharepoint app that is deploy it on online site.

Comment: You want to create library in App only? or on the host web? also which app you are creating? SharePoint Hosted or Provider hosted? please include this information in your question so that we can help you.

Comment: I want to create  SharePoint Hosted that deploy on online site.

Comment: Please see below answer and let me know whether this approach you were looking for?

Comment: There's no question here... only a goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create list in SharePoint Apps

- Create a SharePoint App Solution in Visual Studio
- Right Click on Project and Click **Add New Item**
- Select "**List**" from the available templates
- Now Select **Picture Library** from the list templates available.

In this way you can create Picture library. This step will be same for `SharePoint Hosted App` and `Provider Hosted App`.

For more information look [SharePoint List in SharePoint hosted App](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/sharepoint-list-in-sharepoint-hosted-app.html)

Note : This created Piture Library can be accessible only in the App Web. And in order to access this list you need to use url like `/Lists/ListName` after your app URL.